# Any way to aggregate multiple columns by counting distinct values in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, google-bigquery, aggregation

I have transaction table in user level, I want to return total unique transaction date for each columns by 6 months windows. I came around the approach but my current query not producing my desired output. Can anyone point me out how to get expected output?

**100% working minimal data and my attempt**:

here is 100% working example with input table schema and value, also I include expected output table schema and values [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/DEMbMf84)

**my current attempt**

here is my attempt to produce my expected output:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE desired_output(
    WITH tbl1 AS (
        SELECT *, 
            user_id, purch_yr
            CASE 
            WHEN EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM tx_date) IN (1, 2) THEN 1 -- 1st, 2nd Quarter 
            WHEN EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM tx_date) IN (3, 4) THEN 2 -- 3rd, 4th Quarter
            END AS half_period,
        FROM (
            SELECT *,
                purchase_date tx_date
                EXTRACT(YEAR FROM purchase_date) purch_yr,
            FROM trans
            )
    ),

    tbl2 as (
        SELECT user_id, half_period, COUNT(DISTINCT tx_date) cnt
        FROM tbl1 GROUP BY 1, 2
        )

    select
        *
        user_id,
        sum(tbl2.cnt)
    from tbl2
)
```

**objective**:

I want total unique transaction date count for each columns in 6 months,so `sum(count(distinct transaction_date))` for each column in 6 months time windows.

**update**

I coded my query in bigquery, since I remember the syntax, but my minimal working data and schema works 100% in SQL Server. Either SQL Server query or bigquery solution would be nice.

**desired output**:

I defined my working minimal output table schema and values in same [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/DEMbMf84). Can anyone share thoughts to work this out as expected? thanks

Comment: Your syntax doesnt look like sql server

Comment: @siggemannen  I agree, I coded for bigquery I forgot sql server query syntax, so open to your suggestion; I updated my post. Do you have any thoughts on this?

Comment: i don't quite see the point of this exercise, every column in your expected result get same value per half year period, why do you need every column

Comment: @siggemannen yes, I agree with you. Can you show me how to get sum of each columns values in 6 months time window. Here I produced expected output in this [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/oEltwNxJ). How can I get this?

Comment: Please only tag the **single** RDBMS you want a solution in, as each RDBNS will require a different solution.

Comment: maybe this oen [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/B7QQ5WVJ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base query you're looking is something like this:

```sql
  select user_id, CAST(CONCAT(YEAR(purchase_date), '0101') AS DATETIME) AS purchase_date
  , case when datepart(month, purchase_date) < 7 then 1 else 2 END AS purch_half_period
  , COUNT(DISTINCT purchase_date) AS cnt
  FROM trans
  group by user_id, CAST(CONCAT(YEAR(purchase_date), '0101') AS DATETIME), case when datepart(month, purchase_date) < 7 then 1 else 2 END
```

I'm grouping by user_id, year of purchase, and if purchase falls into first or second 6 month period.

Then to get distinct value, you use COUNT(DISTINCT purchase_date).

I don't quite understand why you need to repeat this value for every column, but yeah, this is basically it.
Usually, the count should consider each column separately, for example, only count purchase date where column X value is > 0 etc. But it doesn't look like it here.

EDIT:

To generate sql for column sums you can do something like this:

```sql
select ',SUM(' + QUOTENAME(name) + ') AS ' + QUOTENAME('sum_' + name)
from sys.columns sc
WHERE sc.object_id = OBJECT_ID('trans')
AND sc.name NOT IN ('user_id', 'purchase_date')
'
```

Comment: thanks for your input. how can we do sum of each columns values in 1st and 2nd 6 months. I prepared expected output in this schema [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/oEltwNxJ). How can we get this expected output? thanks

Comment: you can just add SUM(columnName1), SUM(columnName2),  ... SUM(columnNameN) to the above query?

Comment: in actual dataset, I have 100+ columns with different column name, how can I do this in minimal code? can you show workaround how to do this to get expected table that I showed in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/oEltwNxJ)? any idea?

Comment: You start typing really fast?

Comment: See my edit some some ideas

Comment: Thank you. Does this work for bigquery, Imean this piece `from sys.columns sc
WHERE sc.object_id = OBJECT_ID('trans')`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252594/discussion-between-kim-and-siggemannen).